# Distinct numbers in multiplication table

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, enumerative-combinatorics

Consider the multiplication table for the numbers $1,2,\dots, n$. How many different numbers are there? That is, how many different numbers of the form $ij$ with $1 \le i, j \le n$ are there?

I'm interested in a formula or an algorithm to calculate this number in time less than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: A nice paper on this with plenty of references: Multiples and Divisors, by Steven Finch, available online from CiteSeer.

Comment: If all you can hope to save is a fractional power of $\log n$
then you ought to keep track of powers of $\log n$ in the computation model
and complexity estimates; and then, even if you use repeated addition
rather than multiplication to get each row of the multiplication table,
the direct method seems to take $n^2 \log n$ time and space if you count 
honestly (i.e. $\log n$ bits for a number of size $n$).

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108912/number-of-elements-in-the-set-1-cdots-n-times-1-cdots-n/108939#108939

Answer (score 29):

This is the multiplication table problem of Erdos. According to Kevin Ford, Integers with a divisor in 
$(y,2y]$, Anatomy of integers, 65-80, CRM Proc. Lecture Notes, 46, Amer Math Soc 2008, MR 2009i:11113, the number of positive integers $n\le x$, which can be written as $n=m_1m_2$, with each 
$m_i\le\sqrt x$, is bounded above and below by a constant times $x(\log x)^{-\delta}(\log\log x)^{-3/2}$, where  $\delta=1-(1+\log\log2)/\log2$.

Erdos' work on this problem can be found (in Russian) in An asymptotic inequality in the theory of numbers, Vestnik Leningrad Univ. Mat. Mekh. i Astr. 13 (1960) 41-49.

Another reference is http://oeis.org/A027424 where a PARI program is given.

Comment: Thank you for references!

The PARI program implements straightforward $O(n^2)$ algorithm. Is there any algorithm which works faster than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Ford's _Annals of Mathematics_ preprint is on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401223

Comment: @GerryMyerson "the number of positive integers $n\le x$, which can be written as $n=m_1m_2$, with each 
$m_i\le\sqrt x$, is bounded above and below by a constant times $x(\log x)^{-\delta}(\log\log x)^{-3/2}$, where  $\delta=1-(1+\log\log2)/\log2$". That bound is asymptotic bound. Is there a minimum $x$ needed for that bound to be effective?

Comment: @VS. I don't know. Have you looked at the paper to see how the bound is expressed there?

Answer (score 12):

There's a beautiful lecture by Carl Pomerance in which he discusses Erdos's Multiplication Table Problem and then goes on to talk about dense product-free sets of integers. The talk was at the JMM in Boston in 2012. It's available at

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/sumproductboston.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the algorithmic question, a recent paper of [Brent, Pomerance, Purdum, and Webster](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04251) presents a subquadratic algorithm to compute the number of distinct products $M(n)$ of the $n \times n$ multiplication table.  They have implemented their results to compute $M(n)$ exactly for all $n \leq 2^{30}$.  They note that for larger values of $n$, exact algorithms become impractical, and so the paper also presents two Monte Carlo algorithms to approximate $M(n)$. Monte Carlo computations are presented for $n$ up to $2^{100000000}$.