# Lattice points in dilated polytopes and sumsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, combinatorial-geometry

Let $P$ be an integral polytope, that is, the convex hull of some points in $\mathbb{N}^d$.

Let $p_1,\dots,p_m$ be *all* lattice points in $P$.

**Question:** What is the condition on $P$ that guarantees that every lattice point in the dilation $nP$ can be expressed as $k_1p_1 + k_2p_2 + \cdots + k_n p_n$, where the $k_i$ are non-negative integers? Here, $n \in \mathbb{N}$
and $k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n = n$.

*Note that not all $p_i$ need to be vertices of $P$.* 
Clearly, all *vertices* of $nP$ are expressible in this manner, since they are dilations of the vertices in $P$.

*Remark:* The function $f(n)$ which counts lattice points in the dilation $nP$ is an (Erhart) polynomial and the $g(n)$ that counts the number of points that *can* be expressed as $k_1p_1 + k_2p_2 + \cdots + k_n p_n$ is *eventually* polynomial (Khovanskii).

Thus, we must impose some extra condition on the $p_i$s to have polynomiality all the way, and also equality.

Are there some non-trivial examples of such polytopes?

Comment: Good question.  I asked a related question in a special case (where the answer was negative): see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151869/an-integrality-question-about-expressing-an-integer-as-a-product-of-numbers-belo

Comment: Ah, yes, interesting! The polytopes I have in mind are GT-polytopes, which have a lot of oddities (nice ones thought), so this might be true for these particular polytopes.

Comment: The way you state it, it is not clear what you mean by "question 1 is true/false". Supposedly you mean "Do all such $P$'s guarantee...", don't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second question is known to be true by a theorem of Khovanskii: that is, $g(n)$ is 
eventually a polynomial for large $n$.  Khovanskii also compares this number with the Erhart polynomial -- that is he shows that the $n$ fold sums are approximately contained in the $n$-th dilate of the polytope (this is not so hard).  But I don't know of good conditions which guarantee that the Khovanskii polynomial is the same as the Erhart polynomial.  For Khovanskii's work see Theorem 1 in his paper Newton polyhedron, Hilbert polynomial, and Sums of Finite sets; translation from Russian of his paper in Functional analysis & Applications 1992   (http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~chenhuayi/conferences/okounkov/khovanskii.pdf).

Comment: Ah, thank you, this put me into a nice track. I found a proof of eventual polynomiality here: www.emis.de/journals/JTNB/2002-2/NathansonRuzsa.ps‎. I have to read a bit more, but most results only give polynomiality for n large.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Nathanson and Ruzsa, which I hadn't seen before.

Comment: You are welcome. Now, when I read the paper by Nathanson and Ruzsa, they define something which is called "height" of a point in $\mathbb{N}^d$, which is just the sum of the coordinates. They use this in an essential way, and the problem I am looking at has a nice property related to this. Maybe that can explain why I get polynomials for those...

Answer (score 3):

Toward the first question, there is a theorem (due mostly to Bruce Reznick) that says if $K$ is a lattice polytope in $R^d$ such that the group generated by $(K \cap Z^d) - (K \cap Z^d)$ is the standard copy of $Z^d$ (*projectively faithful*—referring to the corresponding product type action of the $d$-torus on the obvious UHF C*-algebra), then $(d-1)K$ has the property you mention, and $d-1$ is sharp in the sense that for every $d \geq 3$, there is a counter-example with anything less than $d-1$. Moreover, $nK$ has the property for every $n \geq d-1$ (this is relatively easy to obtain, once the $d-1$ result is available). Hence if your set $\{p_i \}$ is of the form $K \cap Z^d$ with $K$ projectively faithful, then you have the result with $n \geq d-1$. This is also the sharpest result if we restrict to simplices.

Some results of this type can be found in

DE Handelman (me), *Positive polynomials and product type actions of compact groups,*
Mem AMS 320 (1985)

DE Handelman, *Positive Polynomials, Convex Integral Polytopes, and a random walk problem,* SLN 1282 (1987).

The $d-1$ and $n \geq d-1$ results are in one of these, but I can't locate the monographs at the moment, so I can't tell you which one of the references has them.

When $d \geq 5$ (and possibly with $d \geq 4$), weird things can happen wrt this kind of problem; see the examples in

D Handelman, *Effectiveness of an affine invariant for indecomposable integral polytopes,* J Pure and Applied Algebra 66 (1990) 165–184.

Comment: Why don't the results mentioned in my post earn the bounty? A sufficient condition for the condition is that $P = k P'$ where $k \geq d-1$. On the other hand, not even normality is enough to guarantee sufficiency.

Answer (score 3):

The polytopes in the question are called [Normal Polytopes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_polytope)

Comment: ... or *integrally closed* or having the *integer-decomposition property*. A nice reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5755.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $g(n)$ is strictly less than $f(n)$, although they have the same leading term.
One sufficient condition to get $g(n)=f(n)$ is to require smoothness of the corresponding toric variety. Combinatorially, this means that at every vertex $q$ of $P$ there are exactly $\dim P$ edges coming out of it; moreover if you take $q_i$ to be the closest points to $q$ on these edges, the simplex with vertices $q,q_1,...,q_{\dim P}$ has minimum possible volume. I believe the statement is pretty much local near all the vertices: if you can generate all points in $kP$ that are close to any given vertex, then you will be able to eventually generate all points.

Edit: I made a mistake in claiming that $g$ and $f$ have the same leading term. This only 
happens if the differences of points in $P$ generate the whole lattice. A simple counterexample in dimension three is the convex hull of $(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,N),(0,1,N)$
for some $N$.

Comment: So, for example if the polytope happens to be a simplex, it is smooth?

Comment: No, smoothness is a very strenuous assumption. It means that if you write $q_i-q$ in a basis of the lattice, the determinant of the resulting matrix is $\pm 1$. It may however hold for the polytopes you are interested in.

Comment: Ah, ok. Hm, so let me visualize, the $q_i$:s are the closest lattice points on edges going out of $q$, which are in the boundary of $P$?

Comment: Yes. It is probably fairly easy to write them explicitly for GT polytopes -- these just might give smooth varieties (maybe some repeated projective bundles)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have changed the formulation of the question slightly to now require identity for all $n$, not just for large ones (or maybe it was just me misreading the original post),
let me offer a sufficient condition.

If you can find a triangulation of $P$ with vertices $p_i$, so that the number of maximum simplices equals the normalized volume of $P$, then you are done. If you can describe GT polytopes explicitly (I have a vague idea of what they are, but not working knowledge), then it might be possible to see if there is such a triangulation.

Comment: I can find the vertices explicitly. I checked the condition on all vertices having the same degree, but this is not true in general, so they are not smooth. Finding a triangulation in general is too hard in my case i believe; a priori, not even the number of vertices is easy to find (unless the polytope is integral, but then I can only do it by checking all vertices explicitly...) Can you give an explicit family of polytopes that satisfy your conditions, but not being too trivial (say, hypercubes)?

Comment: If you can't even find the points $p_i$, then you have little hope of finding a triangulation or of proving the normality of the semigroup ring (which is what you are asking about).

Comment: I had that feeling: Only a couple of years ago, a proof was provided that some GT-polytopes have non-integral vertices, and there is no known characterization on which polytopes are integral. Hence, finding the vertices (in general), is hard. For a specific instance, one can do it, but it requires a lot of work.