# Table of LCM's vs. table of products

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics

In 2004 Kevin Ford established sharp asymptotics on Erdős' problem on the number of different products $a\cdot b$, $a,b\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

(http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401223, see also discussion here: [Number of elements in the set $\{1,\cdots,n\}\cdot\{1,\cdots,n\}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108912/number-of-elements-in-the-set-1-cdots-n-times-1-cdots-n))

My naive question is whether there are much less different numbers of the form 
$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$, where $a,b\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: I think there'll be about as many numbers of the form lcm$(a,b)$.  Ford counts integers having a divisor in an interval $[y,2y]$, and one should be able to adapt this to counting square-free integers with such a divisor.  Of course, a square-free integer in the multiplication table arises also as lcm$(a,b)$.