# Improvement of a bound on divisor distributions from "Divisors" (Hall and Tenenbaum)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

In the classic text referred to in the title of this question, the bound
$$
H(x,y,2y) \ll \frac{x}{(\log y)^{\delta}\sqrt{\log \log y}},\quad (3\leq y\leq \sqrt{x})
$$
is given, where $\delta=1-\frac{1+\log \log 2}{\log 2}\approx 0.08607\ldots $  after defining $$H(x,y,z)\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} \#\{n\leq x:\text{$n$ has a divisor $d \in (y,z]$}\}.$$
Have there been any improvements on this bound?

Comment: Although the accepted response already leads to Ford's paper, you might also consult the answer to this earlier question: [**MO 108912**](http://mathoverflow.net/a/108939)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Kevin Ford](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401223v5.pdf) has determined the order of $H(x,y,z)$ for all ranges of $x$, $y$, $z$.  In particular, from his work (see Corollary 2) it follows that for $10 \le y\le \sqrt{x}$ one has 
$$ 
H(x,y,2y) \asymp \frac{x}{(\log y)^{\delta} (\log \log y)^{3/2}}. 
$$ 
In addition to the Annals paper referenced above, you could look at his simpler  [exposition](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607473) which deals specifically with $H(x,y,2y)$.