# Generalized Erdős multiplication table problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples, erdos

Consider multiplication operation $$f(x_1,\dots, x_k)=\prod_{i=1}^kx_i$$ where $x_i\in\{1,\dots, n_i\}$ with $n_1,\dots, n_k\in\{1,\dots,\infty\}$.

What is the cardinality of the range?

At $k =2$ with $n_1=n_2$ this is the standard Erdos multiplication table problem whose estimates are in [Distinct numbers in multiplication table](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table/31666).

Comment: this should be easy to look up. i know it's been done before

Comment: Standard name for the problem?

Comment: How about googling the title of this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is solved for $k\leq 5$ and open for $k\geq 6$. See [Koukoulopoulos's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3236) for more details.